# Parser Error or Server Error in "/" Application and Error in Web Config

Tags: web-config, visual-sourcesafe, server-error

Hi I've been encountering an error in my project. I need to see the changes that I made in my codes but when I run/debug my project there's an error.
[Server Error in "/" Application or Parser Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3CrB.png) and [Error in Web Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAith.png)

I couldn't know the exact reason why I have this kind of error.

I got my project in Visual Source Safe, I copied it in my local so I also compare the codes or the project that I got from the VSS but the codes are just the same. My colleague also try to run the project in his computer and it's okay. So what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your actual error is the red line, which shows you don't have the AjaxControlToolkit added to your project. There are a number of solutions in the SO Q [Could not load file or assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit' after upgrade to .net 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904263/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-ajaxcontroltoolkit-after-upgrade-to-net-4-0) which could assist you as this is likely not VSS related.